# Order symbolic output for complex number Maple 18

Tags: math, complex-numbers, maple

my problem concerns operation with complex number in Maple 18. The issue is the following
i define this complex: 
    `c:=a+i*b;`
then i compute the square: `sort(evalc(c^2))`
and the output is: 
    `a^2+2*i*ab-b^2;`
So, how can i obtain an output like the following?
    `a^2-b^2b^2 +a*i*ab;`
In other word i want an output where the real part precede the complex part.

i have tried with `sort` command but it was not enough ... probably exixts some command to format the output in complex manner but i dont find that ...

thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

In Maple 18 you could use the new [InertForm](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=InertForm) package to get more control over the formatting.

The exact look will depend on the interface. In the commandline (TTY) interface both uses of `Display` below look the same, but both display with extra round brackets around the real part. In the Standard Java GUI the first one has a grey `+` to denote the inert `%+`.

```
restart:

c:=a+b*I:
expr:=c^2:

U := `%+`(evalc(Re(expr)),evalc(I*Im(expr))):

with(InertForm):

Display(U);

                            2    2
                          (a  - b ) + 2 I a b

Display(U, inert=false);

                            2    2
                          (a  - b ) + 2 I a b

Value(U);

                            2              2
                          -b  + 2 I a b + a
```

This is a new way of handling such issues. In older Maple the real and complex parts could have been kept separate in the display by being each wrapped with the ``() operator. And then the actual value could be re-obtained by applying the `expand` command to strip that off. That's not so nice, displaying with extra brackets even in the GUI.